# Will the Typo Rails 3 blogging app run on CloudFoundry?

Tags: cloud-foundry

I'm trying to upload a fresh install of Typo 6.1, which I've simply unzipped and selected mysql as the database. It works fine locally, as one would expect. But when I push it to CloudFoundry, the application won't start. It doesn't give me an error, either, it just refuses to start.

Has anyone else gotten Typo 6 to run on CloudFoundry and if so, what steps did you take to configure it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I got it working at http://typo-jambay.cloudfoundry.com/

Step 1 - Make an edit to Gemfile, newer rake (10.0.3) doesn't seem happy so we should use the same minor update.

Change:

```
gem 'rake', '>= 0.9.2'
```

to

```
gem 'rake', '~> 0.9.2'
```

Step 2 - Make sure you run bundle install with the database that you plan on using. I used postgress, so I made my config/database.yml a copy of the postgres version that is in config.

Step 3 - You can use a manifest.yml file like this and vmc push should take care of everything provided you have a recent version of vmc (gem install vmc --pre):

```
---
applications:
- name: typo
  framework: rails3
  runtime: ruby19
  memory: 256M
  instances: 1
  url: typo.${target-base}
  path: .
  services:
    postgresql-ccdb5:
      label: postgresql
```

Answer (score 1):

Typo 6 is a bit of an old Rails project, but I have got a copy working. It's at http://typo6.cloudfoundry.com

So, to deploy follow these steps;

1. Clone the typo 6 repository - `git clone git://github.com/fdv/typo.git`
2. Simplify the Gemfile, making sure 'mysql2' is in there

   ```
   source :rubygems

   gem 'rails', '~> 3.2.6'
   gem 'mysql2'

   gem 'require_relative'
   gem 'htmlentities'
   gem 'json'
   gem 'bluecloth', '~> 2.1'
   gem 'coderay', '~> 0.9'
   gem 'kaminari'
   gem 'RedCloth', '~> 4.2.8'
   gem 'addressable', '~> 2.1', :require => 'addressable/uri'
   gem 'mini_magick', '~> 1.3.3', :require => 'mini_magick'
   gem 'uuidtools', '~> 2.1.1'
   gem 'flickraw-cached', :require => 'flickraw'
   gem 'rubypants', '~> 0.2.0'
   gem 'rake', '~> 0.9.2'
   gem 'acts_as_list'
   gem 'acts_as_tree_rails3'
   gem 'fog'
   gem 'recaptcha', :require => 'recaptcha/rails', :branch => 'rails3'

   gem 'prototype-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
   gem 'prototype_legacy_helper', '0.0.0', :git => 'http://github.com/rails/prototype_legacy_helper.git'

   gem 'rails_autolink', '~> 1.0.9'
   gem 'dynamic_form', '~> 1.1.4'
   ```
3. Move config/database.yml.mysql to config/database.yml
4. Do a `bundle install`
5. Deploy using vmc, here's the important part. When asked what type of application it is, select 'other' and then select 'rack'. Go on to select ruby1.9 as the framework and make sure you assign a decent amount of memory to the application, at least 128M. Add a new MySQL service to the application also. At this point, the application should deploy and start OK.
6. If you access the application at the moment you should see a Rails 500 error. This is because the database hasn't been seeded. To seed the database you will need to create a tunnel to the database locally so you can run the db:seed rake task against it.

   Create the tunnel like so `vmc tunnel [name of the service]`, select 'none' for the client, when the tunnel binds you should see the credentials and name of the database pop-up. In another console window modify the database.yml file so it has those details, make sure the address is 127.0.0.1, NOT localhost.

   ```
   login: &login
     adapter: mysql2
     host: 127.0.0.1
     username: uzkeDkKwBnkmC
     password: pcf4oP3N2UbdV
     port: 10000


   development:
     database: df67f078353974ccd8b090ccb726c9109
     <<: *login

   test:
     database: typo_tests
     <<: *login

   production:
     database: typo
     <<: *login
   ```
7. With the tunnel still open, run the rake db:seed task - `bundle exec rake db:seed`, once this is complete (it may take a few minutes) the install should be good to go!

Hope this works for you, any problems, just comment on my answer.

EDIT : if jambay's solution works, use it, it's a lot more straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

Have you been able to check the logs on Cloud Foundry via the vmc logs command?